# VBA Extract outlook messages to excel with certain kewords in subject and from a particular outlook account?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have this vba code which I am using in Outlook to export all emails with a certain subject line to excel. I currently have my code set-up to export the emails from the currently active folder at that time, however I want to change this so that only emails from the inbox folder under the account NewSupplier@hewden.co.uk are selected and all the rest are ignored. Could someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks

```
'On the next line edit the path to the spreadsheet you want to export to
    Const WORKBOOK_PATH = "X:\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\NewSupplierSet-Up.xls"
    'On the next line edit the name of the sheet you want to export to
    Const SHEET_NAME = "Validations"
    Const MACRO_NAME = "Export Messages to Excel (Rev 7)"

    Sub ExportMessagesToExcel()
        Dim olkMsg As Object, _
            excApp As Object, _
            excWkb As Object, _
            excWks As Object, _
            intRow As Integer, _
            intExp As Integer, _
            intVersion As Integer
        intVersion = GetOutlookVersion()
        Set excApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set excWkb = excApp.Workbooks.Open(WORKBOOK_PATH)
        Set excWks = excWkb.Worksheets(SHEET_NAME)
        intRow = excWks.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
       'Write messages to spreadsheet
            For Each olkMsg In Application.ActiveExplorer.Inbox.Items
                'Only export messages, not receipts or appointment requests, etc.
                If olkMsg.class = olMail Then
                If olkMsg.Subject Like "Accept: New Supplier Request*" Or olkMsg.Subject Like "Reject: New Supplier Request*" Then
                        'Add a row for each field in the message you want to export
                        excWks.Cells(intRow, 1) = olkMsg.ReceivedTime
                        Dim LResult As String
                        LResult = Replace(GetSMTPAddress(olkMsg, intVersion), ".", " ")
                        LResult = Left(LResult, InStrRev(LResult, "@") - 1)
                        excWks.Cells(intRow, 2) = LResult
                        excWks.Cells(intRow, 3) = olkMsg.VotingResponse
                        Dim s As String
                        s = olkMsg.Subject
                        Dim indexOfName As Integer
                        indexOfName = InStr(1, s, "Reference: ")
                        Dim finalString As String
                        finalString = Right(s, Len(s) - indexOfName - 10)
                        excWks.Cells(intRow, 4) = finalString
                        intRow = intRow + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next
                    Set olkMsg = Nothing
        excWkb.Close True
        Set excWks = Nothing
        Set excWkb = Nothing
        Set excApp = Nothing
        MsgBox "Process complete.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, MACRO_NAME
    End Sub

    Private Function GetSMTPAddress(Item As Outlook.MailItem, intOutlookVersion As Integer) As String
        Dim olkSnd As Outlook.AddressEntry, olkEnt As Object
        On Error Resume Next
        Select Case intOutlookVersion
            Case Is < 14
                If Item.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
                    GetSMTPAddress = SMTP2007(Item)
                Else
                    GetSMTPAddress = Item.SenderEmailAddress
                End If
            Case Else
                Set olkSnd = Item.Sender
                If olkSnd.AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeUserAddressEntry Then
                    Set olkEnt = olkSnd.GetExchangeUser
                    GetSMTPAddress = olkEnt.PrimarySmtpAddress
                Else
                    GetSMTPAddress = Item.SenderEmailAddress
                End If
        End Select
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set olkPrp = Nothing
        Set olkSnd = Nothing
        Set olkEnt = Nothing
    End Function

    Function GetOutlookVersion() As Integer
        Dim arrVer As Variant
        arrVer = Split(Outlook.Version, ".")
        GetOutlookVersion = arrVer(0)
    End Function

    Function SMTP2007(olkMsg As Outlook.MailItem) As String
        Dim olkPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
        On Error Resume Next
        Set olkPA = olkMsg.PropertyAccessor
        SMTP2007 = olkPA.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001E")
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set olkPA = Nothing
    End Function
```

Comment: I'm curious, what version of Outlook are you using? And I assume this code currently works for you (except that it deals with the default inbox?). I ask because I'm not sure `Application.ActiveExplorer.Inbox.Items` even works to get the default box these days.

Comment: Or is this code you presented an attempt to get a particular Inbox but it doesn't work? As it stands I don't think the code you posted can possibly even run without an error.

Answer (score 0):

In the code, I believe this line won't work at all as `Inbox` isn't an attribute of the `ActiveExplorer` object. Without further information I'm going to suggest what I think you need to replace this with to get the behavior you desire.

```
For Each olkMsg In Application.ActiveExplorer.Inbox.Items
```

Remove this line but instead retrieve the Inbox for the account you wish by replacing it with:

```
Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim Items As Outlook.Items

' Get the MAPI Namespace
Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
' Get the Items for the Inbox in the specified account
Set Items = Ns.Folders("accountname here").Folders("Inbox").Items

' Start looping through the items 
For Each olkMsg In Items
```

`accountname here` is replaced by the name of the account you wish to access the `Inbox` folder in. You could retrieve any of the folders by name by replacing `"Inbox"` with the folder of your choice.